# @JsonSerialize with generics

Tags: java, json, generics, jodatime

I have the following code to Serialize LocalDate of joda to a String:

```
public class JodaDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ReadablePartial> {
    private static final String dateFormat = ("yyyy-MM-dd");
    @Override
    public void serialize(ReadablePartial date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).print(date);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JodaDateSerializer.class)
LocalDate sentDate;
```

I would like to pass the dateformat pattern e.g. (yyyy-MM-dd) to the class when I declare it.

I thought to use generics something like this:

```
JodaDateSerializer<T>

T String;
```

But I am not sure how to use it where I declare the sendDate variable:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JodaDateSerializer<???>.class)
LocalDate sentDate;
```

Any help?

Comment: I don't think you can pass the generic type to the DataSerializer. because java erasure the generic type at runtime. At runtime JodaDateSerializer<A>.class is same as JodaDateSerializer<B>.class

Comment: So what do you suggest to me to do? I don't want to write another class serializer just with the date format different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jackson json parser. you can not pass addition parameter to JsonSerialize annotation nor pass generic parameter to  JsonSerializer class.

I think the only way is create a new JsonSerializer sub class for every date format like this:

```
public abstract class JodaDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ReadablePartial> {

    protected abstract String getDateFormat();

    @Override
    public void serialize(ReadablePartial date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(getDateFormat()).print(date);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}

public class LocalDateSerializer extends JodaDateSerializer {

    protected String getDateFormat(){
        return "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }

}

public class OtherDateSerializer extends JodaDateSerializer {

    protected String getDateFormat(){
        return "yyyy/MM/dd";
    }

}
```

Then use the roper DateSerializer class for your field.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
LocalDate sentDate;

@JsonSerialize(using = OtherDateSerializer.class)
OtherDate otherDate;
```

Comment: I wonder how to use the serializer, not on a bean property, but when a String is passed to LocalDateTime parameter in a controller handler.